# Shouldn't a function of data from a PDF repeated over and over on new data eventually yield a Gaussian PDF?

Tags: density-function, central-limit-theorem, gaussian-process, kurtosis

I got into an interesting discussion with a co-worker today and we are not sure what the answer is:

We have $N=1000$ samples from a Rayleigh PDF. We take those $N$ samples, and compute their (modified) sample kurtosis. (ie, kurtosis computation without de-meaning those $N$ samples first). We get a result.

We then take another new batch of $N=1000$ samples, also from a Rayleigh PDF, compute the modified kurtosis, get a result.

etc, etc.

We repeat this about $M=2000$ times. My question is, should the resultant PDF of those results become, or tend to, a gaussian distribution, as $M$ increases? I should think so, citing the CLT, but my co-worker is more skeptical.

**EDIT:** Not there yet, but learning:

So I simulated this for $N = 10$ and $N = 100$, both cases with $M = 20000$. The histograms are shown below. It looks like in the $N=10$ case, the result is still Rayleigh, whereas for the $N=1000$ case, the result is ... gaussian... maybe? I mean, what is that? It seems to have a heavy tail on the right side...

[image]

I also read through some of the links, I cannot find too much on PDFs of functions of data, ... and changing $N$ here shows different results which makes me a little more confused.

Comment: You might enjoy reading [some of our threads about the CLT](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=central+limit+theorem); I think they address this question. You should also consult information on [laws of large numbers](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=law+large+numbers) and [sampling distributions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%22sampling%20distribution%22). Incidentally, this question is easily resolved by running a simulation with a much smaller $N$, to which your argument applies equally well.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the links, I am making my way through the CLT links, although not sure where to start. Regarding the sim: My problem here is that I would run into the problem of determining if my results are gaussian... which as I understand it is a whole field unto itself. I suppose I could eyeball the histogram, but I was hoping for a more theoretical basis.

Comment: If you set $N=10,$ say, then eyeballing the histogram will be more than good enough to settle the question :-).

Comment: @whuber Thanks, Well, I did so, and I put the image up... with N=10 it looks like Rayleigh still, although for N=100 it ... well I dont know, is that gaussian? It seems to make a slightly heavy right-hand tail... not sure of what to make of it...

Comment: "Something looks kind of Gaussian" doesn't make it Gaussian.

Comment: @Glen_b Well thats what I am trying to determine. What is the resulting PDF of this?